# How to start laravel project that I downloaded from github

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I downloaded a project from github but when I try to start with artisan like this:

```
php artisan serve
```

I get errors :

> PHP Warning: 
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\larticles_api/vendor/autoload.php): failed  to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\larticles_api\arti san on line 18
>
> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\larticles_api/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to o pen stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\larticles_api\artisan o n line 18 PHP Fatal error: 
>   require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\larticles_
>   api/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\l articles_api\artisan on line 18
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\larticles_api/v endor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\lartic
>   les_api\artisan on line 18

Comment: composer install

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1- execute `composer install`

2- rename `.env.example` to `.env` and updated it with your database credentials

3- `php artisan key:generate`

4- `php artisan serve`

Comment: is there any to run without `php artisan serve` ?? @Younel

Answer (score 1):

run `composer install`, them `php artisan serve`